# What's the difference between a jumper, a pullover, and a sweater?

Tags: differences, nouns, vocabulary, dialects

Following on [from a recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/difference-between-a-sweater-and-a-sweatshirt), in Australia we have the word ***jumper*** for a knitted long-sleeved garment, typically woollen.

When cosuming foreign media I always assumed the terms ***pullover*** and ***sweater*** were the names of the same garment in either Britain or America but was never clear. How much semantic overlap is there? Are any two or more terms used in the same region and if so how are they used differently? Or is it purely down to regionalism?

I'm also interested in other words that I may have overlooked which are synonyms of any of these three in some areas or some varieties of English. In fact some posters have mentioned ***jersey***, which I have heard many times but I'm not sure if it refers to the same garment or something a bit different.

Comment: This reminds me of the children's joke.  What do get if you cross a sheep with a kangaroo? A woolly jumper.

Comment: I call all these things a "woolly", even if they aren't made of wool but appear to be. I wonder if there is a further regional differentiation for _woolly_?

Comment: See [Difference between a sweater and a sweatshirt](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27549/difference-between-a-sweater-and-a-sweatshirt)

Comment: @Erik: I link to that one from the third word of my question (-:

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Delete?

Comment: A jumper is a guy on top of a tall tower.  A pullover is a good-looking gal who's easy to convince.  A sweater is what you are when the gal's football-playing boyfriend shows up just after the pullover.

Comment: Pullover: I have to pitch in here. Growing up in the UK midlands, this was a light *sleeveless* woollen-type "jumper" - sleeveless being the crucial element. A bit like a body-warmer, but more homely, and often knitted in "Fair Isle" patterns. In the early 80's it was a fleetingly popular retro look with New Wave bands like Echo and the Bunneymen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a lot of regional variation on the meanings of these words. I am only familiar with US English and UK English, others can fill in the blanks:

Jumper: In the UK this just refers to an garment you wear over your shirt for warmth. It doesn't have buttons, and it pulled over your head.

In the US this has a completely different meaning. It is a type of girl's dress, a top, with attached shorts basically. (Google will be happy to show you images.) It has a kind of "little girl" sense to it kind of like pinafore, however, for sure adult women wear them too.

Sweater: In the UK this is the same as a jumper, a garment you wear over your shirt, with no buttons, and is pulled over your head.

In the US this is a similar item, however, a cardigan with buttons can also be called a sweater in the US.

Pullover: again is a garment you wear over your shirt, pulled over your head. The meaning is the same in the US and UK, but it is a pretty uncommon word in the US.

So in the UK it all means pretty much the same, however there are considerable semantic variations in the US.

This is just based on my personal observation having lived in both countries. I am sure there are lots of subtle regional variations. For example, in the UK the further north you go, the more likely you are to use jumper instead of sweater, and vice versa. Though pullover is pretty universal.

Comment: Google gives a good definition for the american usage: A collarless sleeveless dress, typically worn over a blouse. I think that describes it a bit better.

Comment: _Jumper_ is as Arlen says in the US. A girl's top with attached shorts (or long pants) would be called a _jump suit_ in the US.

Comment: In the US, there are two different types of garment that can be called a *jumper*. For adult women (and older girls), it is the over-dress described by the other commenters; however, it can also be a garment for babies and toddlers, in which case it's more of an all-purpose term for anything that includes both a top and bottom, all in one piece, like pinafores, rompers, jon-jons, etc. (but usually not onesies, which are more like just a top that happens to close at the bottom).

Comment: Perfect answer. A "jumper" in the UK is a sweater, in the US it means a Romper, a one piece top and shorts.

Comment: What does "to be pulled over your head" mean? This refers to the way of taking off the piece of clothing?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Putting on and taking off, yes. There’s no opening in the front, so you put it on by pulling it down over your head, not by sticking your arms directly into the sleeves and then closing buttons/a zip on the front.

Answer (score 10):

In Chile, because of the influence of many immigrants from Britain, a sweater is '*una chompa*' — isn't that neat?

American usage:
Pullover is absolutely part of the wardrobe here!  But it needn't be wooly — it can be made of fleece (synthetic) or a lightweight cotton-jersey knit type thing with long sleeves.  Has to pull over the head versus zipping or buttoning up the front.

Sweater — any knitted thing for the top of your body.  Short sleeves, long sleeves, button front, pullover, hooded, etc. You specify the details.  Sweater-vest, hooded sweater, turtleneck sweater, etc.

Jumper — this is actually a dress (no shorts attached—that is a jumpsuit as clarified above) with no sleeves or collar;  it is worn over a blouse or lightweight 'pullover' as we see in Catholic school uniforms here.

Answer (score 5):

Ireland is the same as BrE but we also have a [gansey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guernsey_%28clothing%29).
Ganseys originated in Guernesy, jerseys in Jersey.
A gansey-load of something is quite a lot, the amount you could carry in your gansey.

Answer (score 4):

The word *jumper* is not used for that particular garment in American English, so there's one difference for you. As for *pullover*, I suppose that would be used to refer only to the subset of sweaters that one puts on by pulling them over one's head, which would exclude things like cardigans and some sweater vests.

Comment: Interesting. In Australia a cardigan differs from a jumper in that it is buttoned up so not pulled over the head as is a jumper.

Comment: In the UK also I would say that you can't take *sweater* to mean *cardigan* -- if it buttons up, it isn't a sweater, a pullover or a jumper: it's a cardigan!

Answer (score 4):

In the UK jumper, sweater and pullover are different names for exactly the same thing. A cardigan has buttons.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, all three mean the same thing in British English.  What nobody else has mentioned yet is that we might also call such a garment a [**jersey**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jersey).

Comment: *Jerseys* and *guernseys* were originally specific types of thick fisherman's sweaters, made to designs from the respective islands (I think 'cable-knit' comes into it, but wouldn't swear to it).  I think *guernsey* still has this meaning, but *jersey* has become generic.

Answer (score 4):

In South African English:

- A long-sleeved or short-sleeved knitted garment pulled over the head
  is called a **jersey**. These can be somewhat formal, and are commonly
  part of school uniforms, or work attire, in winter, because of South
  Africa's relatively mild climate. Terms like *cardigan*, and especially, *pullover* and *jumper* are rarer, or never used in everyday speech.
- A more casual, colourful upper garment, often made of synthetic fabrics is called a **sweater**, or if part of a tracksuit, then a *tracksuit top*. According to Wikipedia, these South African "sweaters" are called "sweatshirts" in the rest of the world. Heavier fabric casual sweaters, with or without hoods, are often called *jackets*.

Answer (score 3):

For the AmE perspective:

- 'sweater' is what you call the knitted garment. You really don't call it anything else.
- if someone calls it a 'pullover', we'd understand that you're probably referring to the sweater, but wonder why you'd say it that way.
- if someone calls it a 'jumper', we'd wonder why you're talking about a young girls halter-top informal summer short dress/skirt thing.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea *jumper* was used in AmE in any garment sense! Is *pullover* used in a garment sense at all?

Comment: 'Pullover' is not used in AmE for anything.

Comment: 'Pullover' is indeed used in AmE. A sweater is either a cardigan or a pullover, depending on whether it zips or buttons down the front or not. If it doesn't, you have to pull it over your head (and thus pullover). Generally, though, people use the word *sweater* rather than pullover or cardigan.

Comment: If I remember rightly, in French, a pullover is "un pull",  taken from English.

Answer (score 3):

My daughter and I worked on a fantastic definition of "jumper" together, and it didn't make it to a post because I hadn't logged in first.   Here's my take on my own:

A jumper is an item of clothing that essentially provides, all in one piece, a skirt and a bodice. It is sleeveless and, by definition, is meant to be worn over a blouse or turtleneck.  The jumper can hang from the shoulders to the hemline OR it can have a waistband.  One can pull the jumper over one's head or, in the case of my daughter's jumper, step into it - this depends largely on the neckline.  The extra space (aka, wiggle room) to get the jumper on is usually provided by a zipper and/or buttons.  They can go down the back or on the side.  A jumper is closed all the way around - since I just read this evening that a pinafore (my guess for what the British would call our jumper) is not generally closed in the back (although it could have apron-string ties to keep it in place) - thank you, Wikipedia.

My daughter's jumper has a yoke-style top - that is it has a fairly open front; it has a waistband with both a zipper and button, on one side, for closure.  The combination of the wide opening down the front and the zipper allows her to step into the garment through the top; the zipper closes up and the button secures the waistband.  I have been known to slide the buttons over to keep up with her growth; another adjustment for height, besides raising/lowering the hem, is to tuck in or let out the yoke-style top (where it attaches to the skirt of the jumper).

A jumper is, in my opinion, worn more often by girls than by grown women.  This bias may be generated by the fact that the uniform for many private schools in this area includes a jumper to be worn over a blouse/turtleneck with a sweater (next paragraph) as an additional layer of warmth as needed (cool weather outside, cool classroom temperature inside).  At my daughter's school, their skirts of their jumpers are to be "mid-knee" length; during the course of the year, they grow and the skirts get relatively shorter.  For the older girls (middle school and up), should they still be wearing jumpers, they seem to want their skirts as short as possible - and how "mini" their skirts end up being can be a source of contention (with the administration and/or with parents who notice or mind).

A pullover would be anything like a sweater or sweatshirt or fleece that goes over your head to go on.  It wouldn't have buttons or a zipper except for decoration.  I'd be more likely to say "sweatshirt" or "sweater" and assume the "pullover" part - for instance, a hoodie is a pullover sweatshirt/sweater/fleece that has a hood and I would call it a hoodie.  I don't think that I would call any of my clothes a pullover, although I would know what someone means if they used the term.

As for sweater, I liked the definition from above:  "Sweater -- any knitted thing for the top of your body. Short sleeves, long sleeves, button front, pullover, hooded, etc. You specify the details. Sweater-vest, Hooded sweater, turtleneck sweater, etc."  I would add that the modifications for sweater could include a long-sleeved sweater, a short-sleeved sweater, or a button-down sweater; we wouldn't say "sleeveless sweater", because that would be a vest.

I would also add that a sweater is generally worn for extra warmth and generally it is worn over a shirt or turtleneck - although *some of the very best sweaters, especially those made from the finest materials (angora/silk/cashmere)* a sweater as a top all by itself.  The extra warmth still holds (those fine materials generally trap a lot of heat).  The only exception would be some more decorative sweater made of a light-weight yarn and and open knit for warm-weather wear (as I said, an exception).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The garment Amy describes is a 'pinafore dress' in the UK and is closed at the back. The pinafore that's open at the back is the kind worn by children to protect their clothes. ('Pinny' can also be a colloquialism for any kind of apron.)

Comment: @Amy, considering the regional variation, it might be useful to say where you're from.  (I'm guessing the US?)