# jersey vs sweater

Tags: synonyms

I checked today the definition of "jersey" in Word Reference dictionary (https://www.wordreference.com/definition/jersey) and found:

a close-fitting knitted sweater or shirt

I think that the concepts of "sweater" and "jersey" are broader than I knew. For me, a "jersey" is a tight light shirt with short sleeves used for sports, which include the official shirts used by soccer/basketball/volleyball/etc players. A sweater (= pullover) is a heavy piece of clothing for the chest with long sleeves, used to warm yourself during the winter. Therefore, how can a jersey be a sweater?

I live in a tropical weather in Brazil. I wonder if my difficulty to understand this concept is that we rarely use winter clothes to practice sports.

Comment: *'[Jersey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey), in the Channel Islands (UK), was famous for its knitting trade in medieval times, and because of that original fame, the name jersey is still applied to many forms of knitted fabric, round or flat.'* [source](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey_(clothing))

Comment: This is entirely based on culture.  Many Americans would say they can not be the same, except for those few who actually know the origin of the term "jersey".  Many British would say that "jersey", "sweater" and "jumper" all refer to similar garments.

Comment: [The shirts now commonly worn by sports teams as part of the team uniform are also referred to as jerseys, although they bear little resemblance to the original hand-kitted woolen garments.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey_(clothing)) Wikipedia Jersey (clothing)

Comment: Closely related: [What's the difference between a jumper, a pullover, and a sweater?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27568/whats-the-difference-between-a-jumper-a-pullover-and-a-sweater)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, "jersey" has distinct meanings in UK and US:

UK: synonym of sweater/pullover, a knitted garment worn on the upper part of the body with no opening at the front and (usually long) sleeves.

US: sporty shirt. Usually used by athletes, such as cyclists and soccer, football, basketball and volleyball players. In the case of team players, it usually refers to the team uniform.

Answer (score 13):

**Think of ‘jersey’ as being like an ancient ‘brand-name’ for ‘sweater’**, originating from an island off France,  where they were made, that eventually became synonymous with ‘sweater, pullover, and jumper’ which are other words for similar garments.

A bit like how ‘hoover’ (a brand-name) became the name for ‘vacuum cleaner’, in the UK.

As Jeeped has commented, a ‘jersey’ is a kind of knitted sweater, made in the island of Jersey in the Channel Islands (UK). Jersey is also the name for various kind of stretchy fabrics, such as cotton jersey, which is similar to ‘T-shirt fabric’ that you find in ‘sports jerseys’, and wool jersey which is used for knitted dresses and other items.

Jersey came to be known as any kind of knitted jumper, or sweater, and the words jersey, sweater, pullover, and jumper are interchangeable.

Jersey, sweater, pullover, and jumper are all pulled over the head - they have no front opening.

Whereas ‘cardigan’ traditionally opens all the way down the front, with buttons fastening it, and is made of the same kinds of material as the others.

Lastly ‘jersey’ or ‘jersey fabric’ also refers to a kind of fine knitted cloth of cotton or wool that is drapeable, stretchy, smooth and flowing - of which T-shirt material is an example.

Sweaters (and jumpers, pullovers, and jerseys) may also be hand-knitted - they may therefore show up as bulky and thick, as in hefty ‘cable knits’ from Scotland or the Isle of Skye, thicker than cardboard (like 1cm thick or more - a ‘fisherman’s jumper’ - to keep out the cold) in which case they are not stretchy, not soft or flowing as in ‘jersey fabric’. And sometimes, such garments may also be softer and made with a jersey kind of fabric.

So sweater, jersey, jumper, and pullover are all synonymous and all mean ‘some kind of knitted top that you pull on over your head’.

This article states that jersey fabric was originally of wool, and then expanded to include cotton and other fibres.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey_(fabric)

Comment: Thanks for the historical background of the word "jersey". However, I am intrigued that you have not mentioned "light", "with short sleeves" or "used for sports" not even once when talking about it and I have seen this term used in sports contexts many times. In fact, If I search "jersey" in Google Images, I only see athletic clothing in the results. Isn't your answer missing something? Maybe UK and US English use "jersey" differently ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista To understand the context you need to know that Association football (Soccer) and Rugby football (Rugger) were codifed as winter sports in the UK in the late 19th century. Not only is it quite cold in the UK in winter but the only fabric with any stretch in it was knitted wool so the first proper upper garments for football were long sleeved, lightweight knitted garments, usually called 'jerseys' because that was the common name for a light knitted garment. <continued>

Comment: In the 1950s people still spoke about "football jerseys" in the UK but nowadays we nearly always talk about "football shirts" because we tend to use "jersey" for a heavier garment and the word is not used much now anyway. It seems that the Americans adopted the word from the British but only for football shirts many of which, unlike British football shirts, have short sleeves.

Comment: @BoldBen - "nowadays we nearly always talk about "football shirts" because we tend to use "jersey" for a heavier garment and the word is not used much now anyway" - another victim of Climate Change?

Comment: The famous 'maillot jaune' of the Tour de France is referred to in English as the 'yellow jersey' even though it's more like a tee shirt.

Comment: You mention [cardigan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardigan_(sweater)) which is also a "brand name".

Comment: @BoldBen thanks for the evolution of the word "jersey". Could I summarize it by saying that in UK a jersey is a sweater and in US a jersey is a sport team (eg football, soccer, hockey, volleyball) shirt ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I'm not sure which type of English you're interested in most, but this answer only applies to British English. It is almost completely incorrect for American English. In AmE, jersey _only_ means the athletic jersey, and _sweater_ is the only word used for what this answer describes. A jumper is _only_ something a baby wears.

Comment: @only_pro Thanks for making it clear. That's what I thought. A small correction: a jumper in US is used by some girls/women too, as shown in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumper_(dress)

Comment: @BoldBen I would upvote an answer that contained the information in your comments. It really helps explain why the US use the term jersey in place of "shirt" as in *football shirt* the (originally long-sleeved) t-shirt complete with the player's number and  sponsored logos  that footballers wear today.

Comment: Irrespective of the origin of the words, I would never call a knitted woolly sweater anything but a sweater. Pullover and jersey to me are both lighter and not knitted in wool, like a sweatshirt or a hoodie. I would consider a pullover and a jersey to be more or less synonymous, but a sweater is a different thing.

Comment: I wrote about the origin of ‘jersey’ which is ancient, has been made there ‘since medieval times’ and pre-dates America, (and the football jersey) - as I felt this would allow readers to then see how the words have evolved over time words diverge mix up or become interchangeable. But it’s nice to know where they come from. I didn’t want to digress into cardis. My answer is UK English, as that’s where I’m from. Yes, I normally think of a jersey as being finer than a sweater - being ‘jersey’. Pullover and sweater can be heavy or light in my experience.

Comment: @KateBunting That's true, but I think that it's probably a hangover from the 50s and earlier. The term "Yellow Jersey" became engrained in people's thinking about the Tour and so remained unchanged. I've just looked up "cycling jersey" and it seems that what I, as a very infrequent cyclist, would call a "cycling top" is called a "jersey" by the dealers. However if you look for "running jersey" which would be a similar garment in many ways most of the UK hits you get don't actually call them jerseys when you open the web page. I think the Tour probably influences terminology in cycling.

Comment: @Jelila IMHO you should mention in your answer that it refers exclusively to UK English. I was quite confused when I read it for the first time.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The Cambridge dictionary says that both "pullover" and "sweater" can be in either wool or other fabric, therefore I think that this difference regarding the fabric that you mentioned is personal or a regionalism.

Answer (score 4):

"How can a jersey be sweater?" I don't know but I'm pretty sure if you asked a hockey player, [a fight could likely break out](https://predlines.com/2016/07/17/nashville-predators-sweaters-or-jerseys/) over it. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey_jersey),

> A hockey jersey is a piece of clothing worn by ice hockey players to cover the upper part of their bodies. It is traditionally called a sweater as, in earlier days, when the game was predominantly played outside in winter, it actually was a warm wool-knit covering.

The reality is the answer most likely changes depending on location and demographic. The [Cambridge Online Survey of World Englishes](http://survey.johndal.com/results/) has an ongoing survey regarding common "regionalisms".

It's kind of like asking for a [soda or a pop](https://www.coca-colacompany.com/stories/on-the-map-tell-us-what-you-call-your-drink); either way, you're probably getting a Coke. Unless you're in the dressing room after the game, in which case, a "pop" is really a "beer".

That of course, clarifies absolutely nothing.

ps: I'm a hockey player and I'm NOT going to say what I call it.

Comment: tonic is another term for soda as well.  +1 for the hockey sweater reference from another hockey player. I played on lakes as a kid, and not regularly on indoor rinks  until I went to college.

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays, a jersey is usually a sports shirt.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to Alan Evangelista's accepted answer, and is significantly less detailed.